# Is there a way to override the color of all items in a list-box?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am using WPF for a GUI design and my GUI contains a list-box. In a nutshell, I am trying to make all of the list-box's items the same foreground-color `#FF548E19`. I understand that the foreground color of each individual item entered into the list-box can be defined by the XAML property:

```
Foreground="#FF548E19"
```

Since I am actually using data-binding with a view-model that I've constructed, I can't simply go and set the `Foreground` property for each item because they are populated at run-time. As an alternative, I tried to set the `Foreground` property on the list-box *itself*. This did nothing, all of the items are still showing up with the color *white*.

**Question**

Is there a way to ensure that each binding item (the items populated into the list-box) gets the foreground color `#FF548E19` without manually changing the colors at run-time?

**Update**

One of the comments has asked how I actually populate my list-box with items. So here is the data-binding property that gets shoved into the list-box on property-changed.

```
/// <summary>
/// A list of the failure codes (per entry).
/// </summary>
public List<string> FailCodes
{
    get
    {
        return this.failCodes;
    }

    set
    {
        this.failCodes = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("FailCodes");
    }
}
```

Additionally, here is the XAML property (includes how `ItemsSource` gets bound).

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox_failCodes"
         Grid.Row="0" 
         Margin="0" Background="{x:Null}" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
         BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
         Foreground="#FF548E19" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding FailCodes}"/>
```

Comment: could you provide code of your listbox and how items are added? you can style your items using `itemtemplate` property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx or

Comment: @lukbl Yes, thanks for asking. Of course I can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your markup, use an [item template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) (as [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728760/is-there-a-way-to-override-the-color-of-all-items-in-a-list-box/40729022#comment68685169_40728760)) with a static `Foreground` value:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox_failCodes"
     Grid.Row="0" 
     Margin="0" Background="{x:Null}" 
     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
     BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding FailCodes}"/>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Foreground="#FF548E19" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This will apply to every item bound to the list box

Comment: Let me give this a try and I will immediately let you know how it works.

Comment: @StevieV updated the answer to reflect the code from your question

Comment: That worked amazingly, thanks for the answer and thanks for updating it to match the code in my question. Very helpful.